# How can I use xpath selector on a selector?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-shell

I'm crawling a forum with Scrapy, the HTML of the replies can be different, because some user do `text_align`, some do quotes etc. So I can't find one xpath that would extract the text I need for all these cases.

```
replies_body=response.xpath('//*[@class="post_body scaleimages"]') #selectorList of all the replies
```

This xpath will retrieve the bloc of code for replied I need to parse.
For certain ones I can just straight extract text from it, but from other I need to check if there is a `<blockquote>`, and for other check for another class...

So I want to do something like this:

```
for r in replies_body:
    #if specific class do something
    #if other class do something else
    #else just get the text()
```

The problem is that I cannot use `.xpath()` on my object because it is a selector. So how can I do this? It seems I can use regular expressions on selector but that sounds a bit painful for the task I have to do here.

Comment: A selector does have .xpath() method
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

Comment: I think you can do `r.xpath()` in your for loop